# Running Sinatra app inside Thread doesn't work

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to run a Sinatra app in a new Thread in order to also run some other thing inside my script but when I do:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class App < Sinatra::Base
...some routes...
end

Thread.new do
  App.run!
end
```

Nothing happens and Sinatra server is not started. Is there anything I'm missing in order to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you run "some other thing" using by creating a thread from inside the Sinatra app instead of the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I run the other ruby process in a Thread but from Sinatra application and it works just fine.

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
    threads = []

    threads <<
      Thread.new do
        Some::Other::Thing
      rescue StandardError => e
        $stderr << e.message
        $stderr << e.backtrace.join("\n")
      end

    trap('INT') do
      puts 'trapping'
      threads.each do |t|
        puts 'killing'
        Thread.kill t
      end
    end

    run!
end
```

And I added a control when Sinatra app is exited also kill the open thread.